assert failed: xQueueReceive queue.c:1389 (( pxQueue ))
I have an ESP32-S3 used with an accelerometer ADXL355 and a LoRa module RYLR998. I´m using UART events to handle what I receive from the LoRa module.
Following this example https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v5.2.1/examples/peripherals/uart/uart_events/main/uart_events_example_main.c, I took the code and addapted to my project.
Here´s a piece of the main.c code
At the top:
...

    QueueHandle_t uart_queue;


...
Inside app_main, calling the 'init_uart' function:
...
 

    init_uart(uart_queue);
     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Waiting 50 ms");
     vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(50));
     xTaskCreate(uart_task, "uart_task", TASK_MEMORY * 2, NULL, 12, NULL);
     ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Task 'uart_task' !!!CREATED!!!");
     ESP_LOGW(TAG, "*********************************************************");
     ESP_LOGW(TAG, "After 'uart_task' created");
     ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Free heap memmory (bytes): <%lu>", xPortGetFreeHeapSize());
     ESP_LOGW(TAG, "*********************************************************");


...
The 'uart_task' in main.c

    void uart_task(void *pvParameters) {
      uart_event_t event;
    
      // data received in uart port which is what we receive from LoRa
      uint8_t *incoming_uart_data = (uint8_t *)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    
      ESP_LOGW(TAG, "!!!DEBUGGING!!! ENTERING 'uart_task'");
    
      while (1) {
        // waiting for UART event
        if (xQueueReceive(uart_queue, (void *)&event, (TickType_t)portMAX_DELAY)) {
          ESP_LOGW(TAG, "!!!DEBUGGING!!! ENTERING 'xQueueReceive'");
    
          bzero(incoming_uart_data, BUF_SIZE);
    
          // Print out remaining task stack memory (words)
          ESP_LOGW(TAG, "uart_task high water mark (words): %d",
                   uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL));
    
          switch (event.type) {
          case UART_DATA:
            uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM, incoming_uart_data, event.size,
                            pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
    
            ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_flush(UART_NUM));
    
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Data received from LoRa module: %s", incoming_uart_data);
    
            ///// if the module answers +OK and we are sending data /////
            // so we wait the ack message
            if ((strncmp((const char *)incoming_uart_data, "+OK", 3) == 0) &&
                (strncmp((const char *)is_sending_data, "Y", 1) == 0)) {
              // we successfully sent the message
              // and waiting for the ack
              is_data_sent_ok = "+OK";
              is_sending_data = "N";
              rcv_ack = "N";
    
              ///// start timer /////
              xTimerStart(resendTimer, 0);
              ///// start timer /////
            }
            ///// if the module answers +OK and we are sending data /////
    
            ///// if the module is receiving data, we proccess it /////
            // +RCV=22,length,data,RSSI,SNR
            // extract the components of the received message
            if (strncmp((const char *)incoming_uart_data, "+RCV=", 5) == 0) {
              char *token = strtok((char *)incoming_uart_data, "=");
              // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
              uint8_t count_token = 0;
              while (token != NULL) {
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                count_token++;
                switch (count_token) {
                case 1:
                  Lora_data.Address = token;
                  break;
                case 2:
                  Lora_data.DataLength = token;
                  break;
                case 3:
                  Lora_data.Data = token;
                  break;
                case 4:
                  Lora_data.SignalStrength = token;
                  break;
                case 5:
                  Lora_data.SignalNoise = token;
                  // Send a notification to check_ack_task(), bringing it out of the
                  // Blocked state
                  vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(DELAY / 50));
                  xTaskNotifyGive(check_ack_task_handle);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
            ///// if the module is receiving data, we proccess it /////
    
            break;
    
          default:
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "UART event type: %d", event.type);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      free(incoming_uart_data);
      incoming_uart_data = NULL;
      vTaskDelete(NULL);
    }



The 'init_uart' function is in rylr998.c:

    void init_uart(QueueHandle_t uart_queue) {
      uart_config_t uart_config = {
          .baud_rate = RYLR998_UART_BAUD_RATE,
          .data_bits = RYLR998_UART_DATA_BITS,
          .parity = RYLR998_UART_PARITY,
          .stop_bits = RYLR998_UART_STOP_BITS,
          .flow_ctrl = RYLR998_UART_FLOW_CTRL,
          .source_clk = RYLR998_UART_SOURCE_CLK,
      };
    
      // Install UART driver
      // uart_driver_install(uart_port_t uart_num, int rx_buffer_size, int
      // tx_buffer_size, int queue_size, QueueHandle_t* uart_queue, int
      // intr_alloc_flags);
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(
          uart_driver_install(UART_NUM, BUF_SIZE, BUF_SIZE, 20, &uart_queue, 0));
    
      // Configure UART parameters
      // uart_param_config(uart_port_t uart_num, const uart_config_t
      // *uart_config);
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(UART_NUM, &uart_config));
    
      // Set UART pins
      // uart_set_pin(uart_port_t uart_num, int tx_io_num, int rx_io_num,
      // int rts_io_num, int cts_io_num);
      // When calling 'uart_set_pin', instead of GPIO number, `UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE`
      // can be provided to keep the currently allocated pin.
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(UART_NUM, RYLR998_UART_TX_GPIO_NUM,
                                   RYLR998_UART_RX_GPIO_NUM, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE,
                                   UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE));
    
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "UART Interface Configuration !!!COMPLETED!!!");
    }


When running the program, this is some of the ESP-IDF Monitor output
`2024-04-03 10:12:08 I (312) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Init LED !!!COMPLETED!!!

2024-04-03 10:12:08 I (322) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Waiting 50 ms

2024-04-03 10:12:08 I (382) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Initializing file system...

2024-04-03 10:12:08 I (742) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Partition size: total: 3848081, used: 2646544

2024-04-03 10:12:09 I (742) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Waiting 50 ms

2024-04-03 10:12:09 I (792) uart: queue free spaces: 20

2024-04-03 10:12:09 I (792) RYLR998 TX: UART Interface Configuration !!!COMPLETED!!!

2024-04-03 10:12:09 I (792) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Waiting 500 ms

2024-04-03 10:12:09 I (1292) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: Task 'uart_task' !!!CREATED!!!

2024-04-03 10:12:09 W (1292) !!!SENSING NODE TX!!!: !!!DEBUGGING!!! ENTERING 'uart_task'

2024-04-03 10:12:09

2024-04-03 10:12:09 assert failed: xQueueReceive queue.c:1389 (( pxQueue ))`

There´s some issue on the line 'if (xQueueReceive(uart_queue, (void *)&event, (TickType_t)portMAX_DELAY))', maybe it´s the way I pass the queue handle to the 'init_uart(QueueHandle_t uart_queue)' function, but I got lost there :(
Any help???
I expect to solve my issue...

Where was your uart_queue created using xQueueCreate?
if you are using uart_driver_install for queue creation, then make sure your task size is greater then your BUF_SIZE
Verify that it(UART) wasn't created before when you were creating it.
for example :
if(!uart_is_driver_installed(UART_NUM)) {
// init here
}

below is simple code for using queue
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"

#define QUEUE_LENGTH    5
#define ITEM_SIZE       sizeof(int)

QueueHandle_t xQueue; // Declare a queue handle

void sender_task(void *pvParameters) {
    int item = 0;

    while(1) {
        // Send an item to the queue
        xQueueSend(xQueue, &item, portMAX_DELAY);
        printf("Sent: %d\n", item);

        // Increment the item for the next iteration
        item++;

        // Delay for some time before sending the next item
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

void receiver_task(void *pvParameters) {
    int received_item;

    while(1) {
        // Receive an item from the queue
        if(xQueueReceive(xQueue, &received_item, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
            printf("Received: %d\n", received_item);
        }
    }
}

void app_main() {
    // Create a queue
    xQueue = xQueueCreate(QUEUE_LENGTH, ITEM_SIZE);

    // Create sender and receiver tasks
    xTaskCreate(sender_task, "sender_task", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(receiver_task, "receiver_task", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL);
}


